# aperiodic signal with a wave generator

Tags: generator, measurement, wave, rms

Is it possible to generate a aperiodic signal with a Rigol DG4162 without additional software?

I want to code a True RMS DMM, which should measure periodic and aperiodic signal, generate by the Rigol DG4162.
Frequency: 50Hz-200Hz
Ampl: 3.3V
Offset: 1.65V

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.